# Field ACF - field "txt" for product with product categories. How show value field & generate classes CSS (no one class)

Tags: php, class, advanced-custom-fields

How generate classes for field txt from ACF for loop in Woocomerce

```
product-types + value ACF Field txt 'woo_product_types' example: product-types.shoes,  product-types.tshirt
```

What do I need to add to the code so that I don't create additional fields in ACF for each product?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_acf_field_to_product_loop', 15 );
  function add_acf_field_to_product_loop_title() 
    {     global $product;     
            $product_id = $product->get_id();    
             $woo_product_types = get_field( 'woo_product_types', $product_id );    
         if ( ! empty( $woo_product_types ) ) {         
        echo '<div class="product-types">' . esc_html( $woo_product_types ) . '</div>';     }
     }
```

The code creates only one class, and I need several so that I don't create new ACF fields for all products. I need to style the generated classes to make product tags (different background color for product type)